# Laravel 5.2 add variable to request using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

EDIT: Can this be done by adding a variable to the Laravel cookie in the client using jQuery? I understand the Cookie is attached to the request during GET?

---

Is it possible to add a variable to the `$request` container in Laravel 5.2 using jQuery prior to executing a `GET` route request?

Essentially I am trying to pass a value to a `GET` request and keeping it off the URL as a parameter (and hidden from the user).

My HTML is essentially a menu:

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav nav-pills nav-stacked " id="menu">
    <li id="menu-1">
        <a href="app.url/1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-2">
        <a href="app.url/2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>.....</li>
</ul>
```

When the `a` link is clicked, I want to intercept this and add

```
menuState = 'state';
```

To the `$request` container, then allow the click event to route to the `href` destination.

Now at Laravel end I shoule be able to access its value as:

```
$request->input('menuState');
```

Is this possible on what is essentially a `GET` request so there is no form being posted?

This is an example of adding a URL variable

```
<a onclick="addURL(this)" href="app.url/1">Menu 1</a>

function addURL(element)
{
    $(element).attr('href', function() {
        return this.href + '&menuState=10';
    });
}
```

Can this be done?

```
<a onclick="addURL(this)" href="app.url/1">Menu 1</a>

function addURL(element)
{
   ---> ADD menuState = value to $request container, then continue with GET request
}
```

Comment: So use POST method if you don't want the query strings to show. To add a field value by JS: document.myformname.fieldname = fieldvalue then do document.myformname.submit() if you want to submit with javascript instead.

Comment: Hi @JoeS, understand. But I am trying to do this via a GET as I am not posting a form per se, but rather activating a link redirect with is a GET request. I am trying to avoid manually turning the requests to POST as it will confuse the application routing. This is for the main menu of the app.

Comment: So this is done in rest style and a HTTP GET verb, that means you can do /url/id/action/action2..etc. Since you are using laravel, you can read the Routing doc to get it implemented. Again I'm not aware that you can hide it with GET method.

Comment: Ok, so I guess you want to like highlight the selected menu? This should be done in the actual controller or view file with a conditional check or an array with maybe menu names paired with selected or unselected state. Like if the menu is selected, then add a class attr or something. Hope this is more helpful. BTW, you just just asked a classic XY problem :) heh

Comment: Hi @JoeS I am trying to pass the state of the menu (open / closed) and avoid having this as a variable in every route.  Also the URL looks ugly. Now I see that the $request container is available to the app regardless of how the route is called (GET, PUT, etc). And it contains a bunch of data. How can I add to this data? Did I misunderstand what is possible?

Comment: I also want to avoid Ajax every time the menu state is changed, I want it to happen as part of the next route taken.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'll try to present a more complete solution to your question.

As you pointed it out, your menu url should probably look better; they should have words in it rather than numbers (this is good for SEO too).  The `<a>` href attr can just be set to the relative url like href='home' or href = 'about'.

Now the question is how do you pass the menu state for all the pages. You probably don't want to use the $request variable in this case as menu state I think should be pre-determined for different pages. The controllers should set some menu-state variable array that contains the on/off for each menu. (or simply a string set to which menu is on but then you need to loop through the menus and do conditional check, your choice).

You can probably utilize a view composer for the menu in this case or simply use  view()->share in the serviceProvider if you are lazy. Check the necessary conditions and pass along the result. In this case I think the menu-state should be clear from the url alone accessed in the script with Route::url().

Edit:
Ok. So finally I understand what's going on after that discussion. Here's what I suggest. I wouldn't bother try to persist the menu state. Most sites have the hover effect where the menu just expands on mouseover, then you click on the menu to go to another page on which you want to see the content more so the menu should just be collapsed. If the user really want the choice to have the option of having the menu expanded as default, make that a preference setting in their profile. Leave the toggle JavaScript however as they may still want to collapse the menu sometimes :)

Comment: Ah, sorry @JoesS but either you misunderstand me or I misunderstand you!! I have a menu that slides open and closed. This is the state I want to pass back to the app via the GET. I have already got all routes named and reference those in my code this way. I have a table relating routes to page titles, css code, slug, others. Makes sense? How would you pass the `menu=open` data via get, avoiding the url vars, nor the Laravel way (I do not want it on every route)and also AJAX, as I do not want my server pinged for menu open / close. If this is not possible, then back to the drawing board. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I'm going to ask you how the menu state is determined.

Comment: Hi @JoeS the menu is activated by jQuery to open or close. I just want the next page load (post or get) to load with the menu in this state without visibility via URL and without Ajax notifying of the state change every time clicked. I also want to avoid sessionStorage on the client. The menu is animated and if toggled on page load then you see it do this. I will change the menu state in the PHP prior to the next page load.

Comment: This is a sample of the menu action (http://seegatesite.com/bootstrap/simple_sidebar_menu.html)

Comment: I'd do it with local storage on the client side. Pretty sure that's how it's done, unless you want the state to persist on the next login, then you need to store it in a cache file or database. (Another way is AJAX to modify the session variable. ) You need to be able to determine the state somewhere. GET method reads the url. I think I probably have visited some site with a ?query string attached to the end for something like this. It's not that bad lol. I'd say local storage is the way to go here.

Comment: Hi @JoeS thanks. But see the menu is animated so if I store local, then to close / open after page load you can see the animation. That is why I wanted to do this in server / PHP. Maybe I can do a "one off no animation" on page load? I will check

Comment: The animation is just a transition. You see there's a div with id='wrapper' and a class of 'toggled-2' if it's collapsed. So you just have to set that class to empty on server side and read localStorage variable to add or remove that class every time with JS. Make sense?

Comment: Hi @JoeS, perfect! So how to pass the menuState in GET request??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102122/discussion-between-joes-and-therealpapa).

Answer (score 0):

IMO the simplest way is to prevent link redirection after the click on `a` and add click event to capture this click then use jquery `$.get()` method to add parameters you want and send your request :

```
$('#menu').on('click', 'a', funtion(e){
     e.pereventDefault(); //prevent link redirection after click

     $.get($(this).attr('href'), {menuState: 'state'}, function(response){
         //response variable contain response from laravel controler 
     })
});
```

Hope this helps.